# Click a button on a webpage using Selenium Excel VBA for chrome

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate a process of downloading a form for multiple months from a government website. It requires me to log in to my account and then proceed with clicking some buttons. For some reason, I don't want to use IE automation, and so, I have chosen to use Selenium through Excel VBA to automate Chrome.
I am able to login, however, I can't click on the buttons after login.
My VBA Code till now is as follows -

```
Sub Download2A()

Dim obj As New WebDriver
obj.Start "Chrome", ""
obj.Get "https://services.gst.gov.in/services/login"

obj.FindElementById("username").SendKeys ("myloginID")
obj.FindElementById("user_pass").SendKeys ("myPassword")
obj.FindElementById("captcha").Click

Do Until InStr(1, obj.URL, "fowelcome") > 0
    Application.Wait (DateAdd("s", 1, Now))
    DoEvents
Loop
```

After This, I want to click on a button for which the HTML is

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pad-l-50 pad-r-50" onclick="location.href='//return.gst.gov.in/returns/auth/dashboard'"><span title="Return Dashboard">Return Dashboard</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
```

Please Note, there are other Buttons with the same class. Please guide on how do I click this button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following `xpath` to click.

**XPATH1**:

```
obj.FindElementByXPath("//button[.//span[@title='Return Dashboard']]").Click
```

**XPATH2**:

```
obj.FindElementByXPath("//button[.//span[text()='Return Dashboard']]").Click
```

**Please note**: Provide some wait before interacting the elements.